# How do I access my Windows directory from docker running on wsl?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

As an example, I have installed Audioserve on Docker running Ubuntu via WSL on Windows.
I would now like to add my audio folder but can not navigate to my Windows folders where they exist as I can only see the Ubuntu directory. How do I navigate to my Windows directory?

[Example using Komga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSeaC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out, to get access to a volume this has to be passed when creating the container in Docker, easily done while using Powershell in windows.
For example:

```
docker run -d --name audioserve -p 3000:3000 
-v C:\Users\user\Desktop\Audiobooks:/audiobooks 
-v C:\Users\user\Audioserve:/home/audioserve/.audioserve 
-e AUDIOSERVE_SHARED_SECRET=password -e AUDIOSERVE_TAGS=artist 
-e AUDIOSERVE_MAX_PARALLEL_PROCESSES=24  /audiobooks
```